# uwp c# NotificationsExtensions GroupIcon

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

How do I get this group icon (see image below) appear? In my app, the NotificationsExtensions use for toast notifications, but this icon is not displayed. How can I set it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an image as visual with type `AppLogoOverride` See also: [MSDN Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts)

If you don't specify explicit this logo, the system will draw the app's logo from the `package.appxmanifest`.

Note in the anniversary update (1607 or 14393) the action center UI is quite different.

> **Image Size** – we made some adjustments to the image sizes to make the
>   notification content richer and more informative. The application icon
>   has shrank to 16px by 16px. The AppLogoOverride (when provided) has
>   been enlarged to 48px by 48px. Therefore, make sure your
>   AppLogoOverride image is at least 48px by 48px (and provide higher
>   resolution versions for the different scale factor devices). [Blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2016/06/10/whats-new-for-toast-notifications-and-action-center-in-windows-10-anniversary-update/)

Comment: No, it doesn't solve the problem for me unfortunately. The graphics are so present in my app and I've also defined AppLogoOverride. This graphic is displayed then within the notification but not as group icon.

Comment: Which Windows version do you use?

Comment: I've been using Windows version 1607